# Linux ad hoc mode

Tags: linux, networking, routes, raspberry-pi

I use Raspberry PI to develop network application. I found problem when I connect PI with ad-hoc network. When PI connect to ad-hoc network PI can't ping any device. However, if I ping from other device to PI before, PI can store the path to that device and PI can ping that device. I send ping from PI to IP broadcast (192.168.1.255 in network 192.168.1.0/24) and I use wireshark to capture packets. I don't see icmp packet came out from PI. On the other hand if I ping a broadcast packet with other device, I will see a packet come out from that device. 
I think it is about route discovery process on Raspberry don't perform well on ad-hoc mode (If I connect PI to local network, everything will work perfectly). Could you please give me suggestion.

This is my ifconfig

```
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:b8:30:ad
              inet addr:169.254.98.20  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:22291 errors:24 dropped:12 overruns:0 frame:12
              TX packets:8305 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
              RX bytes:2187504 (2.0 MiB)  TX bytes:1274782 (1.2 MiB)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
              RX packets:110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
              RX bytes:24095 (23.5 KiB)  TX bytes:24095 (23.5 KiB)

    wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:ef:80:12:e7
              inet addr:192.168.1.103  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:1589 errors:0 dropped:1160 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:190 errors:0 dropped:11 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
              RX bytes:604922 (590.7 KiB)  TX bytes:4714 (4.6 KiB)
```

This is my iwconfig

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"AdhocPI"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Cell: 02:11:87:10:D7:41
          Bit Rate:54 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=2/100  Signal level=2/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is wifi-adapter doesn't support adhoc mode. Just change wifi-adapter. It'll work perfectly